# MYSQL 5.6 Innodb buffer Pool is only used 14% out of 128G

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, innodb, percona, mysql-5.6

I'm running Percona cluster 5.6 (mysql 5.6) with 128G memory allowed for the innodb buffer pool.
However, the workbench shows only 14% is being utilised.
Can anybody let me know why the buffer pool usage is so low?
Thanks in advance!

This is my innodb settings

```
innodb_stats_sample_pages=142
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages=142
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages=142
innodb_open_files=4000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_write_io_threads = 32
innodb_read_io_threads = 32
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size =256M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup = ON
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_format_max = Barracuda
query_cache_type = 0
```

Comment: What's your db size?

Comment: Because the amount of your data is 14% of buffer pool. What, you thought MySQL will use all of it if it doesn't need it or what?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:  Your database (data + indexes) is less than 18GB.  Do `SHOW TABLE STATUS` (or a more complex query involving the `information_schema`) to find out "Data_length" and "Index_length" (ignore "Data_free").

Case 2:  You data is bigger than 18GB, but the "working set" is less than that.

In either case, not to worry.

But...  How much RAM do you have?  That 128G needs to be less than RAM; perhaps no more than 80% of RAM.

You might add `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb%';`

Comment: The database size is about 90G and the total ram on the server is 256G. I think it's slowly picking up. It's now up to 22% after 5 hours of running. Just wonder why the whole database is not being cached to the buffer. Is it only buffering what's been queried?

Comment: Many answers: By 'definition' of "cache", blocks are being brought in as needed.  Suddenly loading 90GB would take a long time at startup!  If you had 1TB of data, which 128GB would you pre-load??  Etc.

Comment: It is loading 16KB blocks as needed.  When it gets full (which it won't, based on your numbers), it will bump blocks out, roughly in "least-recently-used" order.

Comment: Thanks Rick! That answers my question!